# confused: computer security & software development career tracks

Tags: career

I'm a recent computer science graduate.  I like computer security and want to be a security architect.

I googled it and saw that the start point is to be a system administrator, but system administration is not my dream job; I especially love to develop software.

Can I be a security architect if I start as a software developer?

Comment: Can you point us to the search results you found?  Seeing those results in context would help us interpret them for you.

Answer (score 3):

Computer security is a very broad field, and software security is as least as important as hardware and infrastructure security.

When developing software, best practice is to design security in from the start and approximately 20% of total project cost many be spent on security.

To answer your question "can I be a security architect if i'm software developer?" definitely, in fact it is highly unlikely taht you would be employed for software security if you did not understand programming.

> i like computer security & wanna be security architect. I googled it &
>   saw that the start point is to be system administrator.

This is certainly not the only starting point, a masters degree in computer security would be a great first step.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, network engineering and system administration will give you the best background for being a "Security Architect". Because you will have to know how everything interacts with one another so you can properly secure it and understand what the purpose of the protocols, programs, etc. are. While having good software development skills is a plus. It is by no means the main component of the job you are looking at.

This is going to vary though depending on the company's security posture and staffing. So what I said is just my personal experience.

Answer (score 2):

Why not "merge" both worlds. If you are interested in security and software development, you could bring your knowledge and interest into your development team by establishing ground rules for software security.
Set rules for testing (functional and security tests), try to break the software you are building and improve the quality and security of your products.