# personal studies to become a security expert

Tags: professional-education, career

I'm a little late, I'm 21 always been interested in IT and this past year I've looked here and there for computer security, but I don't have a diploma.

I never had any idea on what to do in my life until this year.

this year I'm going back to school and then I'd like to go study computer science to my local university.

I have a little background in programming, I know basic/medium C/C++, same for Python and Java

Now I'm wondering: what should I study by myself to go ahead and learn about computer security?

Can you tell me a "path" to follow? like first TCP/IP Protocol then UDP, then this, then that, a list of subjects to study.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get started with security? (beginner)](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15233/how-do-i-get-started-with-security-beginner)

Comment: Or this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11522/confused-computer-security-software-development-career-tracks

Comment: Also answered here: http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/03/presentations-starting-your-security-career-where-can-you-go/

Comment: i've checked your links, but no one gives an answer to my question... i'd like to know what things you should start learning as a beginner, not which books you should read first.

Comment: The problem is that your question and any possible answers are far too broad. What kind of security? At what level? To what end? Attack/defense? And so on. You need to be exposed to everything and narrow your studies when you find an area that suits you. This field is still too undefined to have a defined "body of knowledge" to direct you towards.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting your "books" comment from, the links @Xander posted are actually all highly relevant to your question, you might just not know it yet. But even if the links posted by him only provided you with suggested books to read, this is actually how you'd "start learning as a beginner". And when you'll end up being an expert, you'll still be reading books (or their online equivalents of keeping up to date) to stay an expert. I'm afraid this is true for all the IT world, and a main reason why Amazon was such a success.

Comment: `I'm a little late` - no, you're more mature and know what you want. If anything, you're right on time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're an American citizen, I would recommend you investigate the [CyberCorps: Scholarship for Service (SFS)](https://www.nsf.gov/funding/pgm_summ.jsp?pims_id=5228) program.  They offer a full scholarship in exchange for your agreement to work after graduation for a Federal, State, Local, or Tribal Government organization in a position related to cybersecurity for a period equal to the length of the scholarship.

This is offered through the National Science Foundation, not the NSA.  The NSA is just one of the federal organizations that might hire you on, but there are thousands of opportunities across the country for security experts.  Lots of cities need people to help secure their infrastructure systems - traffic lights; water, sewer, and electric plants, etc.

The allure is strong:  a free college education, a guaranteed paid job after graduation, and you'll be doing something that you are interested in.

**Edit**  You might also check out this series by Brian Krebs on [How to Break Into Security](https://krebsonsecurity.com/category/how-to-break-into-security/).